# Setter function not getting called on property binding change in WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I have a small piece of code in a user control. That piece of code registers a property as below

```
    Public Shared ValueProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Value", GetType(String), GetType(AutoCompleteBox))
Public Property Value() As String
    Get
        Return Me.GetValue(ValueProperty).ToString
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        Me.SetValue(ValueProperty, value)
    End Set
End Property
```

Simple stuff, right. Nothing special till now. Inside this same control, I have a textbox with following binding

```
Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Value, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

It is supposed to be very simple stuff. Sadly, this code is causing null exception, as Setter method is not getting called at all. I thought, I might be registering it wrong, or missing something. But, I have already gone through five different tutorials to create this property, and yet it is the same problem.

Edit:

Full XAML for the control. I want to update the value property in this control based on the searchtext property change. I tried replacing that autocomplete with normal textbox too, same issue.

```
<UserControl x:Class="AutoCompleteBox"
         xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation" 
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" xmlns:UC="clr-namespace:SMS" >
<StackPanel Margin="0">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" FlowDirection="LeftToRight">
        <Label Content="" Width="auto" x:Name="AutocompleteLabel" Style="{DynamicResource LabelStyle}" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
        <Label Content="*" Width="auto" x:Name="MandatoryLabel" Style="{DynamicResource LabelStyle}" FontSize="22" Foreground="Red" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <telerik:RadAutoCompleteBox x:Name="AutoCompleteTextBox" SearchText="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Value, Mode=TwoWay}" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local" TextSearchMode="Contains" AutoCompleteMode="Suggest" Height="30" Margin="0,0,5,0" GotFocus="AutoCompleteTextBox_GotFocus" KeyUp="AutoCompleteTextBox_KeyUp" telerik:StyleManager.Theme="Windows8" SelectionMode="Single"></telerik:RadAutoCompleteBox>
</StackPanel>
```

Edit:

Screenshot of the issue. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAUlo.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DependencyProperty` you created has a default value of `Nothing` (`null` in C#). So when you call `GetValue(ValueProperty).ToString` then of course a NullReferenceException will throw. What you should do is using the `TryCast` to cast it to `String` in a safe manner:

```
Return TryCast(Me.GetValue(ValueProperty), String)
```

***Edit***: The `Binding` in your code should surely fail, the `Value` property is defined in `AutoCompleteBox` so the Binding should look up the visual tree for `AutoCompleteBox` (which is the `UserControl`) like this:

```
SearchText="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, 
             Path=Value, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

Comment: yes, that's fine. Why is the value null though? That is the problem. I update the text property, then it should update the Value property too, through that Xaml or not?

Comment: @jitendragarg the Binding is 2 way, so the first way is always performed  meaning getter will be accessed first.

Comment: So, after trycast, it should be set properly?

Comment: setting the value does not involve the code in the getter, so of course it should be fine.

Comment: But it isn't. I am still unable to bind the value property. And if I do <classobject>.value, I get nothing. Setter function has a breakpoint which is never reached.

Comment: that's because your binding is not working. And it's of course another problem (not the asked problem where the NullReferenceException is involved).

Comment: It is the same issue. If the setter property is getting called properly, I will not receive any null exception.

Comment: @jitendragarg why do you know that? as I said the getter will surely be called first. BTW do you see any Binding error reported in the ***Output*** window?

Comment: I don't see any binding error at all, even if I change that binding to "ABC123RandomVariable". No errors in output window at all.

BTW, I updated the code to use TryCast. Now, since the value is null, I get exception in other places. Same issue though. Setter method is never called once.

Comment: is this `RadAutoCompleteBox` a standard control in Telerik? As I understand you define the dependency property in this `AutoCompleteBox`, so actually the `RadAutoCompleteBox` won't have any `Value` property, so the Binding should fail.

Comment: Let me clarify. My control is called AutoCompleteBox. Inside that control, I have RadAutoCompleteBox, couple labels and such. I want to be able to say MyControl.Value and get the SearchText property of RadAutoCompleteBox.

Comment: see my edit, the Binding in your code should surely fail.

Comment: Also, if I change SearchText property in RadAutoCompleteBox, I want the Value property in AutoCompleteBox to change, and vice versa. Basically binding my custom property in my custom control to a pre-defined property in a pre-defined control.

Comment: yes Binding should satisfy what you want but if you want the change in SearchText to be reflected back to the `Value` while changing, try setting the `UpdateSourceTrigger` to `PropertyChanged`. So have you tried the code in my edit? how is it not working now?

Comment: Ok, tried the new update. Works now. Thanks. Although, I still can't bind the value from outside the control. Like saying UserControlObject.SetValue(Value, "XYZ") does not work. But, I think, that should work for now.

Comment: Quick question. "AncestorType=UserControl" should be changed to "AncestorType=AutoCompleteBox" right?

Comment: Oh ok. Thanks. I guess, current option is fine enough for now.

Comment: @jitendragarg sorry, I was wrong, in fact you can use `AncestorType={x:Type local:AutoCompleteBox}` instead of UserControl. I've experimented  this before but forgot the experiment result.

Comment: No issues. It works both ways. Not sure if it is advantageous to use one over the other. But, at this point, it does not matter that much.